# UIStoryboardSegue Subclass identify Kind of segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override init(identifier: String?, source: UIViewController, destination: UIViewController) {
        super.init(identifier: identifier, source: source, destination: destination)
    }

    override func perform() {

        self.source.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destination, animated: true)

    }

}
```

In the above code, I am overriding the behavior of segue.
It should use `pushViewController` only if the kind is **Show (e.g.: Push)** for other type it should perform the default behavior that It can.

How do I find the `Kind` of segue in the subclass `perform()` method?

i.e

```
       override func perform() {

            if kind==Push { 
              self.source.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destination, animated: true)
            } else {
              super.perform()
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In storyboard, select segue as custom segue and select kind as custom segue, for default behavior just select show segue (e.g. push)

[image]

Comment: But in the code perform(), how would we know its a custom behaviour. I want to modify it only if its Show(e.g Push)

Comment: You can not get kind from perform. You need to create different segue in storyboard not in code. One segue like custom segue which has push transition and other should be default segue.